# Position a div under another absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a `position` of `absolute`, lets call it `abs`. Directly after (NOT within) that div I create a div called `footer`. `Footer` does not have a position value, although I have tried setting the position to `relative` to the same result. My problem is that `footer` is appearing directly on top of the images I have in my `abs` div despite being declared after that. I'm thinking it has something to do with the absolute positioning of `abs`, because my normally positioned divs behave as I would expect them to: they appear beneath the other divs. Thoughts?

Comment: how about instead of trying to explain what your markup looks like... you just show us the code.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. There are many solutions to the problem, but none that can rely on the absolute element's height being taken into account by the browser's layout engine.

Comment: Do you mean "underneath" as in you want footer further down the page?  On first reading I thought you wanted to control the z-index, but I guess with the name "footer" you mean further down the page.

Comment: Also, can you clarify why `abs` needs to have position:absolute?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are taken _out_ of the flow, so your code is functioning 100% correctly. If you want the elements to be in the flow, don't use `position: absolute`.

Comment: Measure how far the footer is wrongly positioned by and in the CSS `#footer { margin:<measurement>px 0 0 0; }`  This is hackish though and, as Tim says, why would it have to be abs ?  I've written a lot of sites and can't remember using absolute more than about twice - are you sure you need it ? ;)

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I need it is because I'm trying to implement a pure CSS slideshow effect where one image fades into the next. The only solution I've found that seems to be able to do that involves stacking multiple absolutely positioned images of the same size and animating their opacity.

Comment: Ok, so `<div id="container"> many stacked absolute divs in here </div><div id="footer">footer stuff</div>`  Set #container css to required height / min-height .  container & footer are in the flow and the stacked divs aren't.

Comment: @AndyLastname, maybe you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so `<div id="container"> many stacked absolute divs in here </div><div id="footer">footer stuff</div>` Set #container css to required height / min-height . container & footer are in the flow and the stacked divs aren't.